# How to save and send the mote output in contiki

Tags: contiki

I am a new o new one to contiki, I refered the [contiki website](http://www.contiki-os.org/) and executed the sample program.
How can I automatically save and send the mote output to a repository..??

Comment: What do you mean by "automatically save and send"? You can redirect the output to a file, e.g. `make login > filename.txt`. There's also a perl script that logs the output with timestamps appended: `contiki/tools/serial-log.pl`. Do you need something else?

Comment: Thanks @kfx, I am using cooja simulation, when I start the simulation the mote output log should keep storing in a separate file.. Is it possible?? sorry, if I am confusing..

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/wiki/Using-Cooja-Test-Scripts-to-Automate-Simulations . I don't think its possible to output each mote to a separate file. But it's not hard to postprocess the COOJA.testlog file with a custom script to achieve that.